Rewriting the distance based function ( Proposition 24.27) nonlinear analysis
This is from the proof of Proposition 24.27 in Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory.
C is a nonempty closed, convex subset of a Hilbert space $H$. $p=Prox_{f}(x)$, where $f=\phi ( d_C)$, where $\phi: R \to R$ is an even, convex differentiable($R-{0}$).
Suppose $p \notin C$, then since $C$ is closed, $d_C(p) >0$.
We get that
$$p-x=\frac{||p-x||}{||p-P_C(x)||}(P_C(x)-p)$$
$$P_C(p)=P_C(x)$$
I was able to understand the above two steps, but after this, the authors state that the first equation can be rewritten as
$$p-x=\frac{||p-x||}{||p-x||+||p-P_C(x)||}(P_C(x)-x)$$
I am not able to see this, can someone help?
